# Cassandra insert into some tables slow

Tags: java, performance, insert, cassandra

I have a problem regarding inserting Data into cassandra 2.0.3 using the java client.
I'm filling some tables from a textfile using the java api. For some tables, this is extremely fast and for some it's very slow. I don't know why since the structure is very similar and there's not great number of indexes created. Here are some table definitions:

```
  CREATE TABLE partner (primary_uuid uuid, 
       financial_institution varchar, 
       partition_key int, 
       report_date timestamp, 
       change_status int, 
       partner_id varchar, 
       name varchar, 
       surname varchar, 
       seat_country_code
       risk_country_code varchar, 
       legal_form varchar,
       PRIMARY KEY (partition_key, partner_id));
   CREATE INDEX ON partner(change_status);
   CREATE INDEX ON partner(partner_id);
   CREATE INDEX ON partner(seat_country_code);
   CREATE INDEX ON partner(risk_country_code);
   CREATE INDEX ON partner(legal_form);
```

Inserting data into this table is not really fast but acceptable (I guess it's because of the indexes)

Table "deal"

```
 CREATE TABLE deal (primary_uuid uuid,
       financial_institution varchar, 
       partition_key int, 
       report_date timestamp, 
       change_status int,
       deal_id varchar, 
       deal_type varchar,
       risk_type int,
       amount float,
       currency_code varchar,
        PRIMARY KEY (partition_key, deal_type, deal_id));
  CREATE INDEX ON deal(change_status);
  CREATE INDEX ON deal(deal_id);
```

Inserting Data into this table is extremely slow and sometimes it causes cassandra to crash (or at least throw an exception)

Therese table 3:

```
  CREATE TABLE allocated(primary_uuid uuid,
       financial_institution varchar, 
       partition_key int, 
       report_date timestamp, 
       change_status int,
       report_name varchar,
       deal_type varchar,
       risk_type int,
       currency_code varchar,
       ....more columns
       legal_form varchar,
       seat_country_code varchar,
       partner_id varchar,
       PRIMARY KEY (partition_key, report_name, primary_uuid));
   CREATE INDEX ON allocated(financial_institution);
   CREATE INDEX ON allocated(seat_country_code);
   CREATE INDEX ON allocated(legal_form);
   CREATE INDEX ON allocated(deal_type);
```

Although this table is way more complex than the others and I'm setting 4 Indexes on it, insertion into this table is extremely fast and I get to insert thousands of records in a short time. Also, it is about 100 Times bigger than the "partner" table.
I don't understand why inserting into "deal" crashes my application on a regular basis.
The strcuture is simple, the composite key is of the same structure as in "allocated" and there are only 2 indexes. The Java code is also the same, I use BoundStatements for all of them.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: My gut feeling is that you got an OS/hardware problem on a node. Did your instances show any sign of software/hardware trouble recently?

Comment: No the nodes (3 Nodes: 4Cores, 8GB Ram each) are new and other applications that I've tested on them (Oracle and riak) work fine. 
I'm processing insertions on alle three tables in a row in the same process. First I fill "Partner", then "deal" and then "allocated".
Speed for partner is OK, deal is terrible or crashes, and Allocated is fast. So I'd cross hardware off the list

Comment: Since Cassandra is a JVM program, grab a JVM monitor such as VisualVM and keep eyes on it while loading deal data, see if you can catch something

Comment: Aside from @HowardGuo's excellent point, have you tried with different drivers?

Comment: So I uses JVisualVM to monitor the application. Everything looks normal and I can't find any memory leaks. However, I caught this exception when inserting into deal: `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)`. So I guess this is more of a Cassandra problem. After I abort this insertion I continue inserting into allocated with the same instance (no restart of the program) and I get to push data in there very fast. Maybe I have to go with another table scheme.

Comment: So I changed some parameters in the cassandra.yaml config file and now it works. It's slow, but it works